# List calendars and events from users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to read the calendars and events of two users to create an event for both users.
The documentation says it should be possible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

`GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar`

This should give me the users default calendar.
I tried this on the graph explorer page (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and i always get the same error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
        "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-09-22T06:40:48",
            "request-id": "cc36cb73-348a-4062-a07b-70cf4617e7cc",
            "client-request-id": "6932f760-f6b2-5d40-5350-c380917725f2"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same error with `calendars`, which should give me all calendars. Without the `calendar` i retrieve the user details, so the id is ok. Any idea or hint why it is not working?

Comment: Do you use application permissions or delegated?

Comment: the permission type is 'Application'

Comment: Graph Explorer supports only delegated permission type. And for delegated permissions you can get another user's calendar if another user has shared a calendar with you, or, you have given delegated access to that user.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars

Comment: holy...you are right! thanks! please post this as an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph Explorer supports only delegated permission type.

For delegated permissions you can get another user's calendar if another user has shared a calendar with you, or, you have given delegated access to that user.

Resources:

[Get calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Get shared or delegated Outlook calendar and its events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-shared-events-calendars)